# Which operating system gives R the most memory?

Tags: memory, r, operating-system

So far I have been using R on a 32-bit Windows XP machine resulting in 2 GB of available memory to R (using `--max-mem-size=2047M`). In a recent project involving permutation tests (using the `coin` package) this was not enough (i.e., `cannot allocate vector of size ...`).

Therefore, **I would like to run R in an environment that gives me the most memory**. I have a 4GB quadcore PC available for this endeavor (not my desktop PC, so I could play around with it a little and even use it via remote desktop).
Which operating system should I use to use the most memory? **64bit Windows (i.e. 7) or Linux?** If Linux, which distribution?
So far, I haven't used Linux at all so ease of use and installation would definitely be a plus. Furthermore, so far I have been using Notepadd++ and NPPtoR and it would be great if I could stay with this, too. However, most available memory is the primary target.

Comment: XP, Vista, Windows Server 2003 also have 64-bit versions, it's not just Windows 7, and Windows 7 has 32-bit versions too.

Comment: Were the answers here useful to you? Any chance of some feedback?

Comment: Thanks for all the helpful comments. So far I don't see any special benefits by changing to Linux. Therefore, I will start with one of the windows 64 versions. I hope my 4GB of RAM will be enough, because I cannot change the program in any way (usage of the `coin` package eats up all the RAM).

Comment: You may also want to check out http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigmemory/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to talk about Windows in this answer. I know nothing substantial about other operating systems so I'll not embarrass myself by not talking about them.  I'm not making any judgements about which of Windows or Linux is better or worse than the other.

Nowadays, you always want to be using the 64 bit version of Windows rather than the 32 bit version. The 64 bit version of Windows runs 32 bit programs perfectly (sometimes even a little faster than the 32 bit version of Windows manages). When you run a 32 bit program under 64 bit Windows, it can get access to 4GB address space. Under 32 bit Windows it only gets a 2GB address space. So even if you stick to 32 bit R you'll have more head-room under 64 bit Windows.

However, there is nowadays a 64 bit version of R.  This is less mature than the 32 bit version but it will most likely meet your needs. You may need to check for package compatibility since some packages may not yet support 64 bit R on Windows yet.

You may actually experience a drop-off in performance with the 64 bit version of R because pointer width doubles and so the memory footprint is bigger. However, I'd be surprised if this was at all significant.

You can install both 32 and 64 bit versions side-by-side, but if you can get away with just one version I'd always recommend doing so - it makes maintenance so much easier.

As your machine only has 4GB of memory anyway, there's probably not that much to be gained from using the 64 bit version of R. The 64 bit version of Windows will make a big difference, but if you go to the 64 bit version of R as well, and actually use 4GB of memory then you are likely to see lots of disk thrashing and your calculations will take forever.

Finally, when faced with memory resource shortages it is often possible to find alternative ways to organise your code so that you simply avoid the issue altogether. Since we don't have the details of your R code, we can't tell if that is the case here, but it may be worth thinking about.

Comment: Also see the FAQ for more on 64-bit Windows R: http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#Should-I-run-32_002dbit-or-64_002dbit-R_003f

Comment: Thanks, I should have put that reference in, I referred to it quite a bit whilst writing this answer.

Answer (score 3):

Either GNU/Linux or Windows can give R plenty of memory if it is available in contiguous form. GNU/Linux is probably a better choice if you have no specific need for Windows, and Ubuntu is where most people seem to start these days.

The major limit in R is the length of a single vector which is 2^31 (though you can have lists of multiple maximum length vectors), but that should be plenty for most purposes and is more than your 4Gb.

Comment: Why would you say GNU/Linux is better? Considering that Henrik has been using Windows in the past, wouldn't it be easier to stick to that? Unless there was something that couldn't be done on Windows?

Comment: Because it's (almost totally) free as in freedom. :) Otherwise I always use Windows because of other needs. I don't know much about the technical details, but I'm pretty happy in Windows 7 with 64-bit R, it's been a long time coming. I would stick to windows if that's all you know and you're not feeling adventurous, both have many pros and cons for all sorts of reasons.   I had forgotten (see James' answer) that versions of 7 have lower limits on RAM, 16Gb for Home Premium for example - that's an important limitation to consider.

Comment: @mdsumner I know where you are coming from, I just don't think it's always practical for people to switch OS for such reasons. I don't think the licensing limitations are, in practice a consideration. For example it's more of a limitation that the Home editions on support a single processor. If you are going to stick 32GB in a machine you are going to want more than 1 core. I must admit I've never used 64 bit R, but 64 bit Windows certainly does work very well. One wonders why R is so thirsty for memory - now that would be something worth fixing!

Comment: I agree, but I would try not to assume that GNU/Linux or Windows was the "more natural" for anyone, you don't have to move far to find people's assumption switching really fast. The key is in my caveat: "if you have no specific need for Windows". BTW, see Ihaka's papers and talks for possible future moves for (an) R (-like language): http://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~ihaka/?Papers_and_Talks

Comment: @mdsumner I've heard a bit of this already. There does seem to be a degree of disgruntlement with aspects of R.

Comment: near perfect things always upset people

Answer (score 2):

If you want to max out your available physical memory, you should go with Linux as it does not need any unneeded GUI to be run as in e.g. MS Windows. This is no offense against commercial applications, just a practical choice :)

And also, if you really want to max out your RAM, choose a minimal (KISS) system instead of Ubuntu, or go with [Ubuntu Server](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/LowMemorySystems) or with [CLI version](http://www.ubuntu.com/server). I would rather suggest [Debian](http://cran.at.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian/) or [Arch](http://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/i686/r/).

If you are not familiar with Linux, check a simple install on e.g. on howtoforge.com and run R via `R` command in the terminal. Also, choose an image with *amd64* in the filename to download (64 bit). Good luck!

Comment: You can run R on Windows without the GUI too.

Comment: @James: of course you can run R commands as scripts or in Rterm, but I meant not launching a graphical interface (GUI) with bells and whistles at all. So starting Linux in command line without any unneeded process running in the background (dealing with windows, mouse and so on).

Answer (score 1):

The Windows flavours are more limited in the total physical memory recognised by the OS than Linux (256TB), even in 64 bit mode.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778(v=vs.85).aspx#physical_memory_limits_windows_7

Windows 7 Ultimate
 192 GB

Windows 7 Enterprise 192 GB

Windows 7 Professional 192 GB

Windows 7 Home Premium  16 GB

Windows 7 Home Basic  8 GB

Windows 7 Starter 2 GB

So it would depend on which version you have. If you had one of the better versions, it may not be such a limit given the resources available in your system.

Comment: On the type of hardware that most people run R on, the limiting factor is more likely to be how many memory sticks you can fit on the motherboard. I don't know about you, but the workstation I use don't have room to install 256TB, even if I could afford it!! Henrik has stated that his machine only has 4GB anyway.

Comment: Yes, given his current configuration, only the Starter edition should limit his capabilities, but if he were to expand his system, he might start hitting the limits on the other versions too. I wasn't suggesting he might want to install 256TB of RAM, merely that's what the limit is.

Comment: Fair enough. My point is more that I've never come across a workstation that can accommodate anywhere near 192GB. There server versions of Windows can accommodate more than 192GB. If you can afford 192GB you can afford something better than Home Basic! The limits will not be imposed by the Windows licence.

Comment: Bring it on though, and software that can use it to feed hungry GPUs!

Answer (score 1):

Well in my experience with switching from Windows to Ubuntu, i would say that Ubuntu is probably the way to go. I didn't conduct any formal tests, but i did notice some appreciable speed up in some of my analysis (typically involving large datasets). The OS is much more stable also, which is a definite plus, as at least the system doesn't crash if R runs into trouble.

If you do go with Ubuntu, gedit is probably the best editor to start with. You can get a plugin which will open an R window underneath the text editor space, and its quite similiar to N++. Gedit comes preinstalled with the distribution.

Ubuntu is also extremely easy to install - i've put it on two machines (at home and work) and never had any problems with it. And if you can use R, then you can definitely handle command line interfaces.

That being said, the most recent version of R available through Ubuntu is 2.11.1, so you'll need to follow the instructions on [this](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/) page to get the more recent version. HTH.

Comment: R managed to crash your Windows installation? Really? Were you running Windows 98 or something?

Comment: no, just big data sets and a really terrible computer. My own fault really.